# VisualStudio2010 OpenGL project crashes with 0x000007b right on start

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, glew

I try to setup a simple VisualStudio2010 OpenGL Project

I start with a new Win32 project and replace _tWinMain with the following:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    //MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_GLPREDICTOR, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    if (hdc == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    if(!SetPF(hdc))
        return FALSE;

    mainApp = new GLPredictor(hdc);

    HGLRC tmpContext = wglCreateContext (hdc);
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, tmpContext);

    //create opengl 4.2 context
    /*GLenum error = glewInit();
    if(error != GLEW_OK)
        return false;
    int attributes[] = {WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
                        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
                        WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
                        0
                        };

    if(wglewIsSupported("WGL_ARB_create_context")==1){
        HGLRC context = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hdc, NULL,attributes);
        wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
        wglDeleteContext(tmpContext);
        wglMakeCurrent(hdc,context);
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }

    int glVersion[2] = {-1,-1};
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &glVersion[0]);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &glVersion[1]);
    std::cout<<"Using OpenGL: "<<glVersion[0]<<"."<<glVersion[1]<<std::endl;
    */

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_GLPREDICTOR));

    MSG msg = {0};
    while(TRUE)
    {
        // Check to see if any messages are waiting in the queue
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            mainApp->render();
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

This runs.

But as soon as i uncomment the commented region (//create opengl 4.2 context) and try to run the app, then i get instantly an error message saying:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b). Click OK to close the application.
```

but the uncommented code isn't even reached. I can set a breakpoint even on the first line of _tWinMain and it won't be triggered.

I already tried to create a new project and copy the code over, with the same result.

Anyone got an idea why this region causes the project to crash, even if the code it contains is executed?

//edit: the offending line seems to be

```
 GLenum error = glewInit();
```

as soon as it's in the code, it makes the application crash (although code execution never reaches it). Does this line cause the compiler to add some stuff that may cause the problem?

Comment: You have Visual Studio. Did you debug into it to find out where exactly it ran into a problem?

Comment: as written, as soon as the code is there, the application crashes even before reaching the main function. no debug point is triggered

Comment: Well, have you tried uncommenting pieces of it to isolate exactly which line is causing the problem?

Comment: see //edit in the original problem. as soon as this line is in the code, it will crash

Comment: okay - actually, if i create a new Win32 project, add the newest glew32.lib (from glew-1.7.0) and just add 'GLenum error = glewInit();' it will cause this problem

Comment: Looks to me like you somehow pasted the error message wrong.  Exit code 0xc000007b only makes sense.  Triggered by finding the wrong bit-ness of a DLL.

Answer (score -1):

Okay - I got it. I had to copy "glew32.dll" into my SysWOW64 directory

Comment: Don't do that. Don't mess with system directories. Instead copy dll besides your exe file - usually in Debug and Release folders.

Comment: Alternatively, set aside a directory that you put .dlls in, and then edit your PATH environment variable to include them.